# How to make a ScrollRect move smoothly?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Imagine a Unity (2019.2.5) app (not a game) that looks like this:

- A simple tab-bar to switch between views. (just a few buttons that en-/disable other panels).
- Each view contains a `ScrollRect` at which the actual content is displayed.
- There's nothing fancy on the panels displayed inside the `ScrollRect`s. No animations, just plain vanilla UI components like `Text`, `Button`, `Toggle`, `Slider` and a few `Images`.

The problem is that all of the `ScrollRects` scroll a little sluggish, which I'd like to improve (i.e having it scroll smoothly). Taking a look at the profiler revealed the following on a four year old phone (LG Nexus 5X):

1. CPU Usage - rendering: takes about 50 milliseconds.
2. CPU Usage - UI: takes about 2 milliseconds while standing still, while scrolling on average 6ms.
3. UI Layout - takes on average 2-3 milliseconds
4. UI rendering - takes on average 1 millisecond

So it seems like the CPU is the bottleneck. However, the app isn't doing anything (this is really just diplaying UI). The question is, **how can the CPU usage for rendering be improved?**

There's an interesting little detail in the timeline of the "Main Thread":

- PlayerLoop takes about 60 ms.
- EarlyUpdate.PresentBeforeUpdate takes about 35 ms, PostLateUpdate.FinishFrameRendering about 12ms (both displayed at the same row)
- Graphics.PresentAndSync: 35 ms
- Device.Present: 35 ms
- All other displayed values are below 5 ms.

Do you have any ideas what could cause the 35ms for presenting? Or how to debug this to get a little deeper information?
Any ideas are welcome. Thank you!

**Update:**
This is a thermal throttling issue:

When the device is cold, each frame takes about 33ms and Unity is waiting for 15-22 ms each frame for VSync. As soon as the device is getting hand warm, all out of a sudden each frame takes about 60-70 ms. To verify this, I've placed the phone on an ice block and the frame time is stable at 33ms since.

The question now is: Is there anything that can be done against it?

I've just moved the app over to the LWRP, well, and it **feels** like it now takes a little longer until the issue shows up, but it's certainly not fixed... Splitting the UI onto different canvases will most likely not have any difference. A quick test with empty views showed the same problem...

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The problem is probably that your entire UI gets redrawn when the scroll view updates (and your UI contains hundreds of other items). You need to isolate those changes with a child canvas.

Comment: Yep disable any view that is not visible, disable layout group once they are done positioning item, finally, more complex, reuse items so if u have 10 visible items, there are only 12 objects (one up and one down to appear when scrolling). As soon as one gets fully out of view, disable and replace at the other end with next item to show.